# I do not understand the functioning of the css codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter PHP programmer, and am facing a problem of setting css, divs achieve include the templates created in the views folder as header, content and footer, css settings functioned normally, but there is a resource that is in CodeIgniter get the template to be in the views folder and you deploy the css settings, and this feature did not work. I'll put the lines of code to give you an idea.

file /controllers/home

```
    <?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('html_header');
        $this->load->view('cabecalho');
        $this->load->view('menu_categorias');
        $this->load->view('conteudo');
        $this->load->view('rodape');
        $this->load->view('html_footer');
    }
}
```

file  html_header.php

```
<?php echo doctype('xhtml1-trans'); ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Meu website de receitas</title>
        <?php
        $meta = array(
            array('name' => 'robots', 'content' => 'no-cache'),
            array('name' => 'description', 'content' => 'Meu website de receitas'),
            array('name' => 'keywords', 'content' => 'Receitas, doces, salgados, sobremesas, massas'),
            array('name' => 'robots', 'content' => 'no-cache'),
            array('name' => 'Content-type', 'content' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'type' => 'equiv')
        );
        echo meta($meta);
        echo link_tag('assets/imgs/fork.ico', 'shortcut icon', 'image/ico');
        echo link_tag('assets/css/teste.css');
        ?>
    </head>
<body>
```

file cabeçalho.php

```
<div id="tres"></div>
```

file conteúdo.php

```
<div id="dois"></div>
```

file html_footer.php

```
<div id="quatro"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

file teste.css

```
#tres{
    width: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    float: right;
    border: solid 5px #000;    
}
#dois{
    width: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    float: right;
    border: solid 5px #003399;

}
#cabecalho{
    width: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    float: right;
    border: solid 5px #333;
}
```

what not working in css and settings that were placed to # header.

I would like to know how to put to work.

Comment: cabeçalho.php or conteúdo.php should not contain special caracters.. try to change them to cabecalho.php and conteudo.php and see what happens

Comment: there was no change. continuing with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this sintax:

```
$linkCss = array(
    'href' => 'assets/css/teste.css',
    'rel' => 'stylesheet',
    'type' => 'text/css',
    'media' => 'screen'
);

echo link_tag($linkCss );
```

And did you load HTML helper?

```
$this->load->helper('html');
```

Comment: there was no change. continuing with the same problem